# Qual index (php ou html) carrega quando estão ambos presentes?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, html

Gostaria de saber qual arquivo index carrega em caso de ter um index.html e um index.php no site.

Digamos que esteja montando um site em PHP, mas precise do servidor para testes e etc, então faço uma página simples em HTML e coloco lá... Assim ficaram dois index (um html e outro php). Qual seria carregado quando alguém entrasse no site?

Comment: Por mais que seja um exemplo, se o intuito for realmente testar algo seria melhor ter um diretório somente para teste e fora do acesso público, se não um outro servidor realmente, um para produção e outro para teste. ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acabei não conseguindo dos jeitos informados e a página sempre carrega o PHP primeiro :... Então coloquei um código no topo do meu PHP que verifica se eu passei (na url) um valor 'true' para a variável 'testing' e, se SIM, ele carrega meu PHP, do contrário (se eu não passar nada) ele redireciona para o meu index.html. Segue o código abaixo para quem mais precisar de algo parecido com isso :P

```html
<?php
if($_GET['testing'] != 'true'){ ?>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/index.html" />
  </head>
 </html>
<?php } else {
 /* aqui o código PHP */
} ?>
```

Dessa forma, ele carrega meu HTML se eu entrar na URL `example.com`, mas se eu entrar em `example.com/?testing=true` ele carrega meu PHP.

Obrigado pelo apoio! :)

Answer (score 7):

No caso de um servidor APACHE, você determina a ordem através da diretiva `DirectoryIndex` no seu `httpd.conf`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```

Há também a possibilidade de fazer essa configuração no seu `vhosts` de forma individual para cada domínio!

Essa ordem define quais extensões o servidor vai procurar primeiro, na falta de um, ele busca o próximo da lista.